# Loading content with ajax, footer and content briefly move up

Tags: ajax, position, footer

I'm working on my new portfolio and although it's far from finished, i'm getting close to finishing the design. There's just one problem atm that I don't know how to get rid of. If you go to http://minimalito.be/index.html you'll go to the homepage, then when you click on 'about' you'll notice that the footer very briefly jumps to the top of my page...

When you go from the homepage to the about section, not only the footer moves, but the whole content briefly moves up. Would anyone know why?
The content is loaded with ajax, so that's probably got something to do with it, maybe i'm positioning some divs wrong? I don't really see it.

This is rough layout of my code, for more detailed code + example, you can check the website itself of course.

Thnx!

```
    <div id="content" class="block">
        <div id="header">
            <nav class="centered">
                <h2><a href="index.html" class="menuLink">minimalito.</a></h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="design.html" id="aboutLink" class="menuLink">about.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="work.html" id="workLink" class="menuLink">work.</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="contactLink">contact.</a></li>
                </ul>       
            </nav>
            <h1 id="contact" class="ninja">minimalito@info.be</h1>

          </div>
            <div id="load">Loading</div>

            <div id="page">


            </div>
            <div id="footer">

          </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `#header` has a fixed position so it is not part of the document flow.
`#content` has a top margin that pushes both `#content` and `#footer` down so that they are positioned below `#header#`.

Now when you click on one of the menu links at the top `fadeOut` is called on `#content` which sets `display: none;` on it. With nothing left to push elements that are part of the document flow down anymore `#footer` is moved all the way to the top of the page until the new content is asynchronously loaded.

Instead of having `fadeOut` set `display` to `none` consider just changing the `opacity` and replace the content when the element is invisible.

Comment: Yes, works perfectly! Thnx mate. Just one more thing though; when going from the homepage to the about page, the content still overlaps my 'slogan' for a short period of time, and then it adjusts itself to the correct position. Even though i've been using fadeTo now instead of fadeIn or fadeOut.

Comment: It is actually not the `#page` being moved up but the browser scrolling down. Your *about* link links to the anchor `#design` and on your front page you have a `div#design`.